# Why am I not able to run/debug google app engine "hello, world" on eclipse 3.7 (indigo)?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am starting to think something on my eclipse has gone completely wrong. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the plugin, also restarting my computer but nothing has worked.

I also don't think it's a bug, at least not a known one because I've been searching around and haven't found anything about such a problem (I'm doing the app using java).

This is the error I get when I right click the project and select Run as Web Application:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching CodeLabEx0".
org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel
```

And this is what happens when I right click and try to Debug as Web application:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching CodeLabEx0".
com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException
```

And when I select Run configurations... I get this:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com/google/gdt/eclipse/suite/launch/ui/WebAppArgumentsTab
```

and

```
No tabs defined for launch configuration type Web Application
```

Am I missing something really dumb?

Comment: longshot but, not knowing your os/version ... I recall some issues with eclipse, appengine, and the standard Java version on macs.  I replaced the sun jdk with open jdk and it fixed it. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm on Windows 7 64-bit, and that my android projects run fine.

Comment: Are you running both GPE and android plugin on the same eclipse?
I know from experience that they don't mix well, to fix it i have 2 eclipses with a plugin for each.

Comment: @Rohan Thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running both GPE and Android plugin on the same eclipse? I know from experience that they don't mix well, to fix it i have 2 eclipses with a plugin for each.

Answer (score 0):

For me, switching from the OpenJDK to the Sun JDK fixed it.

---

**Linux Instructions**

Download the [sun jdk 6 bin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u35-downloads-1836443.html) and then run the following:

```
chmod +x jdk-6u35-linux-x64.bin
./jdk-6u35-linux-x64.bin
sudo mv jdk1.6.0_35 /usr/lib/jvm/
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/javac 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/java 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/javaws 1
```

Run each of these commands and set your new default java to the sun versions:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Enable Java plugin for browsers.

```
# 64 bit:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins

# 32 bit:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
```